# Error in node-red-contrib-machine-learning

Tags: python, node.js, pandas, machine-learning, node-red

I'm trying to implement the most basic flow of machine learning in `node-red` using this library: https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-machine-learning.

> This flow loads a CSV file, shuffles it and creates a training and a test partition.

[image]

I installed:

- Python 3.6.4 or higher accessible by the command 'python' (on Linux 'python3')
- Numpy
- Pandas
- SciKit-Learn
- Tensorflow (optional: can be skipped)

I opened `node-red` from `Anaconda`.

**The problem:**

When Clicking on "Start" node, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "C:\Users\stava\node_modules\node-red-contrib-machine-learning\nodes\dataset\create-dataset/create-dataset.py",
  line 12, in <module>    df = pandas.read_csv(config['path'], header=None)
File "C:\Users\stava\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
  line 678, in parser_f    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "C:\Users\stava\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", 
  line 440, in _read    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
File "C:\Users\stava\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", 
  line 787, in __init__    self._make_engine(self.engine)
File "C:\Users\stava\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", 
  line 1014, in _make_engine    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
File "C:\Users\stava\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\p...
```

Comment: Looks like a known issue - https://github.com/GabrieleMaurina/node-red-contrib-machine-learning/issues/6

Comment: We found a solution. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Currently, there is a reported and unresolved bug in their repository.
   The bug - Node red can't find any of the files you provided the path to them in the nodes.
   **Solution (Works in Linux distributions and MacOS):** Provide the full path to your files (as we did in this project). ***We couldn't make it work in Windows.***
2. The `decision tree classifier predictor` node accepts arrays in an array of data and returns the prediction. Have a look at how we sent him data from `message to array for prediction` node. Each sub-array corresponds to data that should be sent to get a prediction:

   ```
   return {
           payload: [[...msg.payload.user_code,msg.payload.datetime]]
   };
   ```

[More info and an example of a full working project can be found here.](https://github.com/stavalfi/node-red-machine-learning-project)